# How can I dynamically move buttons and other widgets?

Tags: java, android

I would like to be able to move buttons and other widgets during runtime in my Android java app.

By this I do not mean animate.  Just get layout size, then move and resize widgets while the app is running.

I'm just still new and can't find the methods/classes needed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a layout file in which you have your button with the id *"your_button_id"*:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);

/* How to set Values */

int width = 200;
int height = 100;
int marginLeft = 50; // = Horizontal Position
int marginTop = 20; // = VerticalPosition

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layPara=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);
layPara.setMargins(marginLeft, marginTop,0,0);

yourButton.setLayoutParams(layGes, layParaGes);

/* How to get Values */

int width = yourButton.getWidth();
int height = yourButton.getHeight();
int marginLeft = yourButton.getMargin().getLeft();
int marginTop = yourButton.getMargin().getTop();
```

Comment: Hello @julien-100000 , but I can't even get the line "LinearLayout layoutGet=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);" to work.  No mater whether I use R.layout.activity_main, or R.id.activity_main, none seem to be a valid id, so not sure how I can even start.

Comment: That's my problem julien-100000 , I can't find the right class to call to say :    GetCurrentLayoutHandle, then get me width and depth of that Handle.

From there I figure I can set each widget's passing and X,Y, H & W